# Binary to Decimal Converter with C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function-calls

I am new at writing in C, and I am not quite understanding why this programme is resulting in a failure. I feel like it is a result of the method isTrue. The purpose of the method was to ensure that the string entered was an actual integer, but it doesn't seem to work there. I am not really sure why. I get some weird values returned for some reason.

```
/* Program: binToDec.c
   Author: Sayan Chatterjee
   Date created:1/25/17
   Description:
     The goal of the programme is to convert each command-line string
     that represents the binary number into its decimal equivalent 
     using the binary expansion method.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*Methods*/
int strLen(char *str);
int isTrue(char *str);
int signedBinToDec(char *str);

/*Main Method*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /*Declaration of Variables*/
  int binNum = 0;
  int decNum = 0;
  int i;

  /*Introduction to the Programme*/
  printf("Welcome to Binary Converter\n");
  printf("Now converting binary numbers\n");
  printf("...\n");

  /*Check to see any parameters*/
  if(argc > 1)
  {
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if(isTrue(argv[i] == 1))
      {
        if(strLen(argv[i] <= 8))
        {
          binNum = atoi(argv[i]);
          decNum = signedBinToDec(binNum);
        }
        else
        {
          printf("You did not enter a 8-bit binary\n\a");
          break;
        }
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("You did not enter a proper binary number\n\a");
        break;
      }
    } 

    /*Printing of the Result*/
    printf("Conversion as follows: \n");
    printf("%d\n", decNum);

  }
  else
  {
    printf("You did not enter any parameters. \a\n");
  }
}

int strLen(char *str)
{
  int len = 0;
  while(str[len] != '\0')
  {
    len++;
  }
  return len;
}

int isTrue(char *str)
{
  int index = 0;
  if(str >= '0' && str <= '9')
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}


int signedBinToDec(char *str)
{
  int i;
  int len = strLen(str);
  int powOf2 = 1;
  int sum = 0;

  for(i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if(i == 0)
    {
      powOf2 = powOf2 * -1;
    }
    sum = (str[i]*powOf2) + sum;
    powOf2 = powOf2 * 2;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Question conent is good, but where is your research effort?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You are comparing a pointer to a char.  Needs moar dereference.  You got a clean compile, no errors/warnings??

Comment: Please stop trying to write 'clever' code, with compound expressions/statements - you're not very good at it.  Don't feel slighted - nobody is.  SImplify you code until you can easily debug it.  Use temp vars instead of compound expressions in brackets.  printf moar stuff out.  Learn how to use your debugger - don't write any more code at all until you can use your debugger to, at least, step, breakpoint and inspect variables.

Comment: Not directly related, but the name of the `isTrue` function is a very poor choice. Why not call it `isDigit`??

Comment: Unrelated to the question but I think `Date created:1/25/17` should be `Date created:1/25/18`, unless your assignment is overdue for a year :p

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya that's what happens when you copy it from a previous year submission.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I got the code to finally work. I admit I was a little sloppy, so I appreciate all the people who contributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement

```
  if( isTrue(argv[i] == 1) )
```

is very wrong. It is bad because of two cases

- `argv[i] ==  1` is a comparison between a pointer and an `int`, which is illegal. This causes a **constraint violation**. According to `C11`, chapter §6.5.9, *Equality operators*

  > One of the following shall hold:
  >
  > — both operands have arithmetic type;
  >
  > — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
  >
  > — one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or
  >   unqualified version of void; or
  >
  > — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.
- The result of the comparison, again, an `int` value, is being used as the function argument, whereas, the function is supposed to accept a `char *`. An `int` and `char *` are not compatible types.

It appears, you meant to write

```
  if ( isTrue(argv[i]) == 1 )
```

as you need to compare the return value of `isTrue` call.

The same goes for `strLen(argv[i] <= 8)` and others.

---

That said, there are other problems.

- `isTrue()` only checks for the value in index `0`, for the passed argument, you need some sort of loop to check the entire *string*.
- There are already well-known library functions like [`isDigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) which does the work pretty nicely, try to make use of them.

Comment: I WILL use a compound statement.  I WILL not use temporary boolean values.  I WILL not simplify expressions that might be wrong.  I WLL keep getting it wrong, over, and over, again :)

Comment: @MartinJames Please don't make me lose my lunch. I'm done.

Comment: sorry - I hope you keep your lunch where it belongs:)

Comment: @MartinJames Sure thing, off to lunch now, before anything else pops up :)